# Math.Atan2(double.NegativeInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity) - bug, or undocumented breaking change?

Tags: c#, atan2

Consider `double result = Math.Atan2(double.NegativeInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);`.

In .net 4.8 this returns `NaN`.

In .net Core 3.1 or later this returns `-0.7853981633974483`.

The [documentation for Math.Atan2()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-5.0) states:

> If x or y is NaN, or if x and y are either PositiveInfinity or NegativeInfinity, the method returns NaN.

I suppose "either PositiveInfinity or NegativeInfinity" could mean "*both* PositiveInfinity or *both* NegativeInfinity" in which case it would not apply to my example (because x is NegativeInfinity and y is PositiveInfinity) but that seems rather subtle - and in any case, it still seems to be a bug or a breaking change.

So is this a bug or an undocumented breaking change - or am I just misunderstanding things?

(I discovered this because after porting one of our unit test libraries to .net 5 some unit tests started failing because of this change in behaviour.)

Comment: The C function `atan2` gives -0.7853981633974483 (-45 degrees) too (check `man atan2`). It seems like .NET Framework is the odd one out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be the result of [a fix](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/10295) of [a mismatch between the old behaviour and the IEEE 754 specified behaviour](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7510). But the documention hasn't caught up to the new behaviour yet.